# How can I give my users the proof that their data are encrypted?

Tags: security, privacy

I want to implement a feature on my website that will hold private client data.

I want to promote this feature, but how can I give my clients a guarantee or proof that their data are encrypted and that even me cannot have a look at it?

I mean, is there any way they can be sure of what I claim on my website?

Comment: Do you encrypt on the client-side (with JavaScript) or on the server-side?

Comment: When I say encryption, I don't just mean the data transit, but also the data storage. Meaning that their data will remain private and unseen from top to bottom, even from me or database admins.

Comment: So that means you encrypt with JavaScript on the client-side, correct? How do users decrypt the data?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend having a third party come and audit your systems and provide you a summary of compliance, which you can share with your customers.
When I say third party, I mean a separate security company that specialise in IT security audits.

ISO27001 compliance is normally a good place to start when seeking to prove security controls are in place. It doesn't touch much on encryption however.